# Working with adMob

Tags: android, admob, onclicklistener

I was adding some ads to my app with the admod sdk, and I wondered if I can hide the banner after clicking on it, so the user could enjoy the app without ads. I searched it, but I didnt found any proper answer.

I thought about using `OnClickListener` and `OnTouchListener`, but neither of those worked.

I added something like this:

```
adView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    public boolean onTouch(View p1, MotionEvent p2)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v)
    {
        mainLayout.removeView(adView);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to my code... worked great! only thing to do is implement AdListener, and setAdListener, nothing more :D

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdListener
{

public void onReceiveAd(Ad p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad p1, AdRequest.ErrorCode p2)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

public void onPresentScreen(Ad p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}

public void onDismissScreen(Ad p1)
{
    mainLayout.removeView(adView);
}

public void onLeaveApplication(Ad p1)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
//load ad stuff,etc,etc
adView.setAdListener(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the AdListener

These events might work for you

```
public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad)
```

Called when an Activity is created
    in front of your app, presenting the user with a full-screen ad UI in
     response to their touching ad.

```
public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad)
```

Called when the full-screen Activity presented with onPresentScreen has been dismissed and control is returning to your app. public void

```
onLeaveApplication(Ad ad)
```

Called when an Ad touch will launch a new
    application.

[AdMob AdListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/intermediate#adlistener)

Comment: So, where have i to put these lines??

Comment: You activity needs to implement AdListener, i.e public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdListener. Follow the link I gave, there is a complete example from Google you can download.